# In Jquery, append the value then remove that value and again append same value how?

Tags: jquery, html

this is the jquery code, where i append some value and remove that value but i want to
   again append the same value.

```
 <script>
 $(function(e){


 $('#chat-links a').one("click",function(){ 


    var str = "Hi, " + this.id + " What's up?";
    var chatWindow ='<div id="chatWin" class="chat-window">'+ 
                    '<div  style="width:100%;height:auto;">'+
                    '<a href="#" class="linkClose"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" style="float:right"></span></a>'
                    + str +
                    '<a href="#" class="expand_heading"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus" style="float:right">minimize</span></a>'+
                    '<div class="toggle_container">'+
                    '<div style="width: 100%;height: 150px;background-color:rgb(243, 241, 229);"></div>'+
                    '<textarea rows="2" cols="20" style="margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 5px;"></textarea>'+'</div>'+'</div>'+'</div>'
```

$('#chat-stage').append(chatWindow);

```
   $("a.expand_heading").toggle(function() {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
        $("a.expand_heading").click(function() {
            //console.log(this);
            $(this).next(".toggle_container").toggle();
        });

  });

  $('.linkClose').live('click', function(){
         $(this).parent().parent().remove();
         return false;
    })`enter code here`
    $("#chat-links a").click(function () {

         $('#chat-stage').add();

});
 });

</script>

in this code firstly i append value and  after i remove the same value but i want to 
add the same value when click the  **"$('#chat-links a')"**

There is Html code

     <ul id="chat-links">
    <li><a id="frooty" href="#">frooty</a></li>
    <li><a id="boby" href="#">boby</a></li>
    <li><a id="bittu" href="#">bittu</a></li>
    <li><a id="biku" href="#">biku</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="chat-stage"></div>
```

Here is the list item ,where i click one of them then the append value are display and i 
   remove the same value which are append, but how to add the same value in same place.

Comment: Its hard to see any purpose of this... What about using data() of object to keep content and then use it to reappend it?!

Comment: Actually i making chat application, where i append the chat window and then i remove this window when press the  close button. But i want to reopen the same chat window how?

Comment: I don't see any code that appends anything anywhere. The closest I can see is `.add()`, but that expects an argument telling it what to add.

Comment: I think you are talking about an element and not a value, and if you're going to reuse the same element I recommend you to hide it instead. There's also the `.detatch()` method to detach it from the DOM when not in use, but note that manipulating the DOM is slow.

Comment: sorry i was not put the append value but i edited our question now.